# Titanium android read exif infromation jpeg

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-android

I am developing an android application which needs to read the exif information of images.
can anyone tell is there any proper method to read exif information in titanium so that i can rotate the image in right way.
If not possible is there any module readily available.
thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

There is no titanium API available to get the exif data of images in android refer [jira](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-3427),you can create your own module for that, also refer this [question](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/33721/exif-data-from-photo-gallery) and the [Exif.js](https://github.com/gstreetmedia/Titanium-Mobile-ExifData)

hope this will help you.